# Reconnect to Domain Controller after temporary disconnect in Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, domain-controller, remote-desktop-services

I have 5 RDP Servers running Windows Server 2012.

Our Domain Controller was temporarily taken off of the network for 5 minutes due to a bad switch.

Even after it has been brought back online, when logging in users get the message:

```
The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.
```

The only solution I know of is to reboot each of the RDP servers. I really do not want to do this, however have to resolve this immediately.

Is there an alternate solution that does not involve rebooting?

Comment: You really ought to deploy a second domain controller. What would happen if this lone DC crashed and you weren't able to recover it?

Answer (score 1):

Check DNS Server if allow dynamic update is set.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771255(v=ws.11).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check the adapters, they may be showing public (which disables RDP by default). Assuming the networking issue is sorted you may be able to use `set-netconnectionprofile -InterfaceAlias "alias" -NetworkCategory Private` in powershell. You can get the alias from `get-netconnectionprofile`.

Answer (score 0):

Flushing the DNS ended up solving the problem.

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```